# How can I use a task queue to perform a long request in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have a function that takes a long time to delete many entities from the datastore.  It produces a DeadlineExceed exception.  I've tried to run it through a task but I'm still having trouble.  In the documentation it says a task can 10 minutes but at the same time the task is calling an end point which has its own limitation.   Therefore I don't see the benefit of the task's 10 minute execution time.

My function that exceeds the deadline is written like this that pulls ~1000 entities.

```
class DeleteJune(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ji = Junk.all().run()
        for j in ji:
            db.delete(j)
```

How can I run a function like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine requests require a response within 60 seconds, else they give a `DeadlineExceeded` error.  If instead, you send the request via the taskqueue, it will wait up to 10 minutes for the response.

Taskqueues are used to hit a url  The url handler should run the script.  So, from one request, you send the taskqueue to another url, via the taskqueue:

```
    from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
    taskqueue.Task(
        url='/your_DeleteJunk_class_url_handler',
        method='post',
        params={'what_to_delete': 'all'}
    ).add(queue_name='some-queue-name-or-default')
```

You need 2 url handlers to do this: one which calls the script to set up the taskqueue, and one that the taskqueue hits to do the job.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't sure if the second handler in your example /your_DeleteJunk_class_url_handler could exceed 60 seconds.

Comment: Yes, that is where the 10 minute limit applies.  The taskqueue will wait up to 10 minutes for the response from that url handler.

Comment: Got it - this worked fine. Took about 2 minutes to run in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to delete everything, you can use mapreduce for that :) Or using the taskqueue as you mentioned, the trick is do batch delete which is faster (your code is deleting one by one) and chaining the task.

```
class DeleteJune(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ji = Junk.all(keys_only=True)
        if not ji.count(1):  # nothing to delete, task is done
            return
        db.delete(ji.run(limit=1000))
        // enqueue same task, or the hacky way just raise 500 here so it will retry :P
```

Haven't really tested the code above, hope you understand the logic.